# Chef Client failed without errors

Tags: chef-infra, chef-client

I've run chef for existing cookbook, however I can't run it correctly.
I've got  Chef Client failed without any error.
[image: Synchronizing Cookbooks: Running handlers: Running handlers complete]

Comment: `-L` option is for logfile. Do you have a file named `DEBUG` with any output? `-l` (small) is the one to set `debug` level of logging to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed up `log_level` option with `logfile`.

- Lower case `-l`: `-l debug`, will set `log_level` to DEBUG for logging to standard output.
- Upper case `-L`: `-L DEBUG` will create `logfile` called `DEBUG` and put the logs/errors of that run in it.

The error might be present in the file at `/home/centos/DEBUG`.